# Will I lost my data or not?

Tags: partitioning

I have ubuntu 12.04 in my system.I stored Data in `/home` Directory
**(I have given one partition of hard disk to this */home* folder)**. and my home directory `/home/user`.

Now my question is that If I format my system(partition in which os is stored) then 
will i lost my data stored in **/home**  Directory?

I know I will lost my data of **/home/user** directory.

Comment: /home/user contains the files for a specific user account.

Comment: your question was not clear.Format my system refers to both formatting the whole disk or formatting a specific partition where Ubuntu is installed.

Comment: the /home directory is already on its own partition. when you format your root partition, the /home paritition will keep intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you make your `/home` on other partition that the `/` partition then you **ARE NOT** going to lost the data unless you will format the /home which you are not going to do.

Just when you format your PC just format the `/` partition and don't touch the `/home` partition then you'll be safe.

---

**Ubuntu Community says:**
Setting up /home on a separate partition is beneficial because your settings, files, and desktop will be maintained if you upgrade, (re)install Ubuntu or another distro. This works because /home has a subdirectory for each user's settings and files which contain all the data & settings of that user. Also, fresh installs for linux typically like to wipe whatever partition they are being installed to so either the data & settings need to be backed-up elsewhere or else avoid the fuss each time by having /home on a different partition.

You can read more about [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving)

Comment: I agree with @maythux. Since you've located your home folder on a separate partition you won't loose data if you only format the specific partition. Additionally, once you've installed you may have to assign ownership to that `home` directory to whatever the new user you're creating after a fresh install. More here on partitioning > https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: Thank you maythux. I was confused because I thought OS is controlling */home* though it is partitioned(*/home*) but now clear.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani You are welcome friend

Answer (score 0):

If you format your system, then yes, you will use that data. I would suggest backing up that information via an external drive, a Dropbox account, or Ubuntu One cloud storage.